# extracting the meaning of a sentence

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp

Is there some java library that helps extract the content of a sentence/paragraph?
Essentially what I need to do is get a context of what is being said (such as whether the sentence is providing a positive or negative point and that sort of thing).

I don't know of such a system and have been looking around and have not been able to find anything useful. does anyone know of something that might help with this?

thanks

Comment: what you ask is way too ambiguous... you should provide us with an example input and the corresponding expected output

Comment: My apologies for the vagueness, not sure if this will help, but what I had in mind is something that would analyse a list of user comments and then determine if the comment is a positive view or a negative view. this is then used by the application to generate a user profile based on his positive/negative comments on different topics. (so I am looking for something to help extract if a user's comment is one agreeing or disagreeing)

Comment: maybe you did not search with the right keywords. try: `sentiment analysis' and/or `opinion mining'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GATE (https://gate.ac.uk/), a NLP & Machine Learning tool.

You can use ANNIE for splitting sentences and POS tagging.
You have to prepare training dataset, with sentiments already annotated manually and then use Batch Learning plugin to predict sentiment for training documents.

Step-by-step tutorial for this: https://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-may10/track-3/module-11-ml-adv/module-11-sentiment.pdf

And the example talked about in the pdf: https://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-may10/track-3/module-11-ml-adv/module-11-sentiment.zip